# Domain and range

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to draw in TeX the following, but I'm pretty new at tikz therefore I have no clue.

I would like to give the geometrical interpretation of the domain and the range of a function.
That is that every element of the function that is defined on that has an image on the axis x'x , and that every element that is evaluated on that particular x, has an image on y'y.

How do I do that? I would also like to have some arrows indicating the whole process.

**Question:** Why can I not write the math symbols in LaTeX here?

[image: http://ebooks.edu.gr/modules/ebook/show.php/DSGL-C105/492/3197,12972/images/imgB1_21.jpg]
<sub>(source: [ebooks.edu.gr](http://ebooks.edu.gr/modules/ebook/show.php/DSGL-C105/492/3197,12972/images/imgB1_21.jpg))</sub>

**Edit:** I want to draw the first two pictures in Tikz, not the third one! Hope this helps.

Thank you in advance.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! As for why code isn't rendered by MathJax, see http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1272/why-doesnt-maths-render-as-maths As for your actual question, do you have a sketch of what you want to achieve? And if you're able to do any part of it, could you add that code to your question?

Comment: I can't do the code of the question. I'm truly sorry. How do I upload images?

Comment: There is a button just above the text field, click that to upload an image. When that is done you get something like `![enter description][1]`, you need to remove the `!` I think, as users with <10 rep can't add images to posts.

Comment: I have just a link to an image! Hope this helps, but I don't want to draw the third one... Only the image on the left and the middle one...

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I took the liberty to include your image.

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino Thank you very much! That will serve better.

Comment: This should not be closed yet. Please wait at least 24 hours after asking the OP for improvements to the question before voting to close. Also, if you downvote, please don't forget to revert the vote after the question is improved.

Comment: Did I pose a too difficult problem? Because , as far as I can see no - one has answered. I do undestand that tikz needs constant attention so that the result is perfect, but ...

Comment: No, but there aren't always people that 1) has seen your question, 2) knows/can figure out how to answer and 3) has the time to write a proper answer. I'd advice a little bit of patience, it is only a couple of hours since you posted the question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not the most elegant code, there's a bit of trial and error and code repetition, but it does the job.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections,backgrounds}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\draw [thick,-stealth] (-0.5,0) --node[below]{$A$} (4,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw [thick,-stealth] (0,-0.5) -- (0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\node [below left] at (0,0) {$0$};

\draw [ultra thick, red] (0.5,0) -- (3.5,0);


\coordinate (start) at (0.499,0.7);
\coordinate (stop) at (3.501,2.5);

\fill (start) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (stop) circle[radius=2pt];
\draw [name path=curve] (start) to[out=-35,in=190] node[pos=0.6,above left] {$C_f$} (stop);

\foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,3.5}
  {
  \path [name path=line] (\x,0) -- (\x,3);
  \draw [name intersections={of=curve and line},dashed,-stealth]
   (intersection-1) -- (\x,0);
 }


\begin{scope}[xshift=6cm]
\draw [thick,-stealth] (-0.5,0) --  (4,0) node[below]{$x$};
\draw [thick,-stealth] (0,-0.5) --node[left]{$f(A)$} (0,3) node[left]{$y$};
\node [below left] at (0,0) {$0$};

\draw [ultra thick, red] (0,0.52) -- (0,2.5);

\coordinate (start) at (0.499,0.7);
\coordinate (stop) at (3.501,2.5);

\fill (start) circle[radius=2pt];
\fill (stop) circle[radius=2pt];
\draw [name path=curve] (start) to[out=-40,in=190] node[pos=0.6,below right] {$C_f$} (stop);

\foreach \y in {0.52,.916,...,2.5}
  {
  \path [name path=line] (0,\y) -- (4,\y);
  \draw [name intersections={of=curve and line},dashed,-stealth]
   (intersection-1) -- (0,\y);
 }

\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \draw[-latex] (-1,0) node[below right = 0mm and 5mm] {$O$} --
            node[pos=0.55,below]{$A$} (10,0)node[pos=0.99,below] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,-1)  -- node[pos=0.99,left] {$y$}(0,8);
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (a) at (2,3) {};
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (b) at (8,6) {};
    \foreach \x [count=\y]in {0,0.05,...,1.05}{
    \draw (a.center) to [out=-45, in=180]node[pos=\x] (\y){}
           node[pos=0.5,above=1mm]{$C_{f}$} (b.center)
     ;
     \draw[dashed,-latex] (\y) -- (\y|-O);
     \draw[very thick,red] (a|-O) -- (b|-O);
    }
    \node at (5,-1) {($\alpha$)};

    \begin{scope}[xshift=12cm]
      \coordinate (O) at (0,0);
    \draw[-latex] (-1,0) node[below right = 0mm and 5mm] {$O$} --
             (10,0)node[pos=0.99,below] {$x$};
    \draw[-latex] (0,-1)  -- node[pos=0.55,left]{$f(A)$} node[pos=0.99,left] {$y$}(0,8);
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (a) at (2,3) {};
    \node[fill,circle,inner sep=2pt] (b) at (8,6) {};
    \foreach \x [count=\y]in {0,0.1,...,1.05}{
    \draw (a.center) to [out=-45, in=180]node[pos=\x] (\y){}
           node[pos=0.5,below=1mm]{$C_{f}$} (b.center);
     \draw[dashed,-latex] (\y) -- (\y-|O);
     \draw[very thick,red] (4-|O) -- (b-|O);
    }
    \node at (5,-1) {($\beta$)};
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=20pt,12pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-node}
\psset
{
    algebraic,
    ticks=none,
    labels=none,
    xAxisLabel=$x$,
    yAxisLabel=$y$,
    saveNodeCoors,
}

\def\f{-2*sin(3*x/4-1/4)+2.5}

\begin{document}
% a
\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(7,5){10cm}{!}
    \psplot[arrows=*-*]{1}{6}{\f}
    \uput[-135](0,0){$O$}
    \uput[-90](3.5,0){$A$}
    \fnpnodes[plotpoints=10]{1}{6}{\f}{P}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\numexpr\Pnodecount+1}{\psline[linestyle=dashed]{<-}(P\i|0,0)(P\i)}
    \uput[180](P6){$C_f$}
    \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=2\pslinewidth](P0|0,0)(P\Pnodecount|0,0)
\end{psgraph}

% b
\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(7,5){10cm}{!}
    \psplot[arrows=*-*]{1}{6}{\f}
    \uput[-135](0,0){$O$}
    \uput[180](0,2.5){$f(A)$}
    \fnpnodes[plotpoints=12]{1}{6}{\f}{P}
    \multido{\i=0+1}{\numexpr\Pnodecount+1}{\psline[linestyle=dashed]{->}(P\i)(0,0|P\i)}
    \uput[0](P6){$C_f$}
    \psline[linecolor=red,linewidth=2\pslinewidth](0,0|P3)(0,0|P\Pnodecount)
\end{psgraph}


% c
\begin{psgraph}{->}(0,0)(-.5,-.5)(7,5){10cm}{!}
    \psplot[arrows=*-*]{1}{6}{\f}
    \uput[-135](0,0){$O$}
    \pnode(*4 {\f}){A}
    \psxTick(N-A.x){x_0}
    \psyTick(N-A.y){f(x_0)}
    \psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed](A)
    \uput[0](A){$A(x_0,f(x_0))$}
    \pcline[linestyle=dashed](A)(A|*5 {\f})\ncput[npos=1.2]{$x=x_0$}
\end{psgraph}
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

[image]